# Powerpoint 2013 Equation tool does not allow full-size fractions

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, equation-editor

I have noticed that, when using the native Equation tools functionality (which has replaced the old Equation Editor) that some of the structures are not allowed in Powerpoint 2013, and specifically they get changed to their more compact counterparts. This is true of the full-size "Stacked Fraction," which gets changed to the "Compact Fraction" with no way that I can find to make it a "Stacked Fraction." This also happens with the limits on summation symbols and integral signs, it automatically changes the forms with the limits above/below the symbol to the forms where the limits follow the symbol. All of the structures work properly in Word, it is just in Powerpoint that they do this. Even taking an equation created in Word and pasting it into Powerpoint will change the formatting of the structures.

Anyone have any ideas how to get Powerpoint to quit doing this? And and all help would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. I have tried using MathType, but I don't like the spacing and line weights quite as well as the native tool, and I also greatly prefer the ability to make the equations in-line with text, as opposed to a stand-alone object as with MathType.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but still valid.

I found out that the problem is related to Display and Inline modes of the equations, and it is the same feature also in Word. When there is any text (even a space) at the same line with the equation, the equation is automatically changed to Inline mode, which shrinks the size of the equation vertically. It is not possible to change this behaviour (that I would call a bug, but of course Microsoft considers it a feature since they do not want to put any effort on developing less used functionalities like Equation editor in general).

However, there is a workaround that can be used quite nicely in Powerpoint, and why not also in Word, although it requires more effort:

The equation can be placed in a separate text box, that includes nothing else. Then this text box can be placed on top of the desired text, where you just leave an empty space for the equation.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way and it's a little hacky but it works, verified in both Microsoft Powerpoint and Microsoft Word. Pro tip at the end.

Most tips online tell you "to create a full sized fraction, create a separate paragraph", which is the same as "I don't know how to do it". To create an in-line equation that DOES NOT shrink the size of the text in the numerator and denominator, there are two cases, one in which the numerator is a longer string of characters, and one in which the denominator is longer string of characters (though you can always just assume that the numerator is longer and add spaces to the denominator to make it fit.

1. Create a new equation. In the equation editor, click the matrix dropdown, and choose the matrix that uses no brackets and is 1 column wide and 2 rows tall.
   [Matrix which is 1 column wide by 2 rows tall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnFG8.png)
2. If your matrix has a longer numerator (such as the quadratic formula or the fraction (a+b+c)/d), go to the top box. Then in the equation editor, click the accents dropdown list, and in the Overbars and Underbars subheading, click the underbar. That's it. Type your numerator and denominator and voila.
   [Underbar used for a longer numerator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKPeR.png)
3. If your matrix has a longer denominator (such as the fraction p/(q+r+s+t), then instead of going to the top box, go to the bottom box. Then click the accents dropdown list, and in the Overbars and Underbars subheading, click the overbar. That's it. Type your numerator and denominator and voila.

Proof that it works: [Note that the numerator and denominator are the same size as the normal text despite the fact that I did not create a new paragraph.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0BYY.png)

Pro-tip: Create a macro so that you can give it shortcut keys so that it takes 1 second to create a fraction.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that it happens when you add text to your math formula. As long as you add symbols within the highlighted area of your formula the limit locations are OK. As soon as you add a symbol outside the highlighted formula area the limit locations automatically changes. It makes sense: you formula becomes a part of the text.

Comment: Can you expand upon your answer a bit?