# PowerPoint equations screwed up

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, equations

Office 2013;
Opening powerpoints from a book publisher, but the equations are all messed up.
Here is picture of before-and-after

[image]

The only fix I know is to double-click on the equation, which opens equation editor, close the dialog boxes and the equation editor, and that fixes one equation at a time.

Is there a better way?

Also, when I right-click on a messed-up equation, PowerPoint crashes. When I right-click on a fixed equation, everything is fine.

Comment: Microsoft changed the way they handle equations in PPT 2013; is it possible that these presentations were created in an earlier version of Office?  If so, there may be some incompatibility between the two that gets resolved when you doubleclick and it does a conversion to the "new" format, perhaps.  It might be possible to automate the fix with a VBA macro. Can you post an example presentation e.g. on OneDrive and give us the link here?

Comment: Yes, this post has more detail   http://superuser.com/questions/744797/powerpoint-2013-equation-tool-does-not-allow-full-size-fractions
I uploaded and tested the Powerpoint here http://speedy.sh/2xgfC/Chapter-5.ppt
 
Someone tried to make a macro addressing the issue here, but I don't understand how to implement it. Not a programmer: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/afa4a094-62f9-4bb7-a590-ed28fd0e2c68/powerpoint-2013-converting-equations-to-images?forum=officegeneral
 
Do you think this compatibility pack works? http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3

Comment: I'll take a closer look later; pressed for time right now.  But the macro from Rich is to convert an equation into an image; if the equation's already messed up, you'll get an image of a messed up equation.  I don't think that'll help in your situation.  The compat pack lets people who use older versions of Office open files created in the newer versions.  Again, no real help for you there either.